# How to compare the responses from two different servers using Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I need to compare the responses from two different servers using Jmeter. I think that **Comparison assertion** in Jmeter supports the response comparison. But how to use this? What is the purpose of 'Comparison filters'?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178810/comparing-two-rest-services-to-each-other/53168556

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need the Assertion as a parent or sibling to your compare requests. Make sure you add the Listener "[Comparison Assertion Visualizer](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#Comparison_Assertion_Visualizer)" to help see the differences/debug

[The Filters](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#Compare_Assertion) are to remove strings you know are dynamic, for example a timestamp or unique userID embedded in the response.  It uses PERL regular expressions, the same as the post-processor Regex Extractor

Here's a sample structure:

```
Test Plan
 + Thread Group
   + Server 1
   + Server 2
   + Compare Assertion
 + Compare Assertion Visualizer
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/98711/blackgaff Thanks for this- if i have a key value in one response and the same key-value pair is not there in the second response- how do i exclude or add filters for scenario like this- where we expect the other response to not have a certain key-value?