# comparing two REST services to each other

Tags: java, unit-testing, rest, jersey, integration-testing

Does anyone have any tips on writing tests that compare two REST services?  We are doing this as a form of regression testing.

I was hoping to do something along the lines of:

1. send a GET for "/1" to both services and compare the results
2. send a POST to both services, and compare the results
3. send a PUT to both services, and compare the results

The idea is that:

- every operation is sent to both services
- the results should be identical

The REST services are written in Java/Jersey, so using that would be ideal, but what have people found to be useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is a broad, non-coding question not strictly related to java, here are some related links:

- The twitter open-source Diffy server, comparing primary, secondary and candidate endpoints: https://github.com/twitter/diffy
- a similar, simpler http proxy: https://github.com/xthexder/httptee
- Someone doing this using JMeter:
  https://dzone.com/articles/the-easiest-way-to-compare-rest-api-responses-usin
- An Example using Postman post-response hooks to compare requests: https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/33232/difference-between-two-responses/2QsCkC
- The Postman approach but using newman, a postman CLI client: https://github.com/indeedeng-alpha/newman-reporter-diff

Anyone feel free to edit my answer to add more alternatives demonstrating API response comparison

Answer (score 1):

I would use [jUnit](http://www.junit.org/) and some of the example test cases from the Jersey source as a starting point. Without knowing specifically how you want to determine "identical" responses, you can make a request to each in your test case and iterate through the response, convert it to a string and test for `equals()`, etc. Here is an example of a [JSONP from JAXB test](http://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/content/trunk/jersey/samples/json-from-jaxb/src/test/java/com/sun/jersey/samples/jsonfromjaxb/MainTest.java?rev=5805).

Comment: Yeah, that works, but I was hoping for a framework that does most of this for me, instead of me having to write anything from scratch.

Comment: jUnit *will* do a lot of the work for you, but it's impossible for it to automatically know that you want exact matches of the responses to `assertTrue` for example. You could very well want to opposite in some cases. Regardless, the implementation would be fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

Write Junit to get the response objects from both services.  And then do the comparison in Java as you do normally for the objects.

But why do you have to write two services that does the same thing and return same results?  Atleast I assume the response objects schema is different between two services.