# Find common fields between two or more API endpoints

Tags: json, rest, comparison

I'd like to compare two or more APIs, and outputting the common records found according to one of the fields.

For instance, given this API:

https://belgianrefugees.leeds.ac.uk/wp-json/brdb/v1/entries

I'd like to compare it with another similar one, which might have different fields, although it certainly have a 'full name' field, as in the first one.

I'm happy to get the JSON of the data I want to compare and run everything from my local machine: this is just a proof of concept and test, I'm not developing a finite product.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178810/comparing-two-rest-services-to-each-other) and since it's dated now and it doesn't do exactly what I want, I'm posting this question. Any language/framework is fine by me. Thanks in advance.

Example:

First JSON:

```
    {
        "entry_id": "460",
        "Surname": "Embrechts",
        "Name": "Karl",
        "Sex": "F",
        "Occupation": "Farmer"
    },
```

Second JSON:

```
    {
        "entry_id": "460",
        "Surname": "Embrechts",
        "Name": "Karl",
        "Full Name": "Karl Embrechts"
        "Sex": "M",
        "Married": "Yes"
        "Job": "Photographer"
    },
```

I want to be able to spot these two record which regard the same person via the fields 'Surname' and 'Name'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the values with ajax. Convert them into objects with JSON.Parse() . Assuming it will be array of values so you will have 2 arrays. Iterate both arrays and compare properties you already know they exist on both side like this :

```
var isTheSame = value1["Name"] === value2["Name"] && value1["SurName"] === value2["SurName"];
```

Comment: actually... how do I store the arrays into variables so that they are available outside the calls?

Comment: @HBMCS Well are "available outside the calls" a little bit broad term. What you can do is to assign them to global variables. But You should notice that ajax calls are async, you may assign to variable but yo need to make sure that the code uses that variable should be running after ajax call is done. You do this by using `async await` or chaining `then`s on returned `Promise`s

Comment: What if I if call a fetchData function (with xhr calls) from within another ceck() function> Something like:

function fetchData() {

const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
reques.open('GET', link, true); etc...

function check() {

        fetchData()
        console.log(data)

}

? Doing so work only after I called the function once. When I call check() from the second time onwards I get the results in the console, not the first time, when it's 'unidentified'. inizilising a data var or an empty array doesn't help.

Comment: In an async world `check() { fetchData() console.log(data) }` `fetchData` has async parts. So some code in that function will complete after function executes. That doesn't guarantee `console.log` operation will work after these operations. What you can do is return a `Promise` from `fetcthData` then chain your log operation like this : `check() { fetchData().then(()=> console.log(data) )} `

Comment: Thanks, I'll study how promise works (never used it before) and will hopefully implement it successflly.